# Can you get the LastRunTime using schtasks /query?

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I am eventually trying to write a script that will count how long a scheduled task has been running for, so we can have it log an error/warning to our database if it runs longer than expected.

At the moment I am trying therefore to find the selection of running scheduled tasks I want to count the time on, and their last runtime (which I should then be able to use to count how long each job has been running for). I am struggling to find the last run time though. 
I currently have:

```
$tasks = schtasks /query /fo CSV | ConvertFrom-CSV
$Task = $tasks | Where-Object {($_.TaskName -like '*Backups*') -and ($_.Status -eq 'Running') }

$Task
```

Output:
[image]

I tried a different way of doing it as well  - with a ComObject but couldn't work out how to get the status from that one:

```
function getTasks($path) {
$out = @()

# Get root tasks
$schedule.GetFolder($path).GetTasks(0) | % {
    $xml = [xml]$_.xml
    $out += New-Object psobject -Property @{
        "Name" = $_.Name
        "Path" = $_.Path
        "LastRunTime" = $_.LastRunTime
        "Status" = $_.Status
        "Actions" = ($xml.Task.Actions.Exec | % { "$($_.Command) $($_.Arguments)" }) -join "`n"
    }
}

# Get tasks from subfolders
$schedule.GetFolder($path).GetFolders(0) | % {
    $out += getTasks($_.Path)
}

#Output
$out
}

$tasks = @()

$schedule = New-Object -ComObject "Schedule.Service"
$schedule.Connect() 

$tasks += getTasks("\DBA\Backups")

[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($schedule) | Out-Null
Remove-Variable schedule

$tasks
```

Output is: [image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a `Get-ScheduledTask` cmdlet which result can be piped to the `Get-ScheduledTaskInfo` cmdlet to retrieve the `LastRunTime`:

```
Get-ScheduledTask | select -first 1 | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo
```

Example output:

```
LastRunTime        : 19.09.2016 09:07:07
LastTaskResult     : 0
NextRunTime        : 20.09.2016 09:07:07
NumberOfMissedRuns : 0
TaskName           : GoogleUpdateTaskMachineCore
TaskPath           : \
PSComputerName     :
```

The `Get-ScheduledTask` cmdlet provides you the status.